# Insert XML Node into a SQL column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an XML file that I am passing into a stored procedure.

I also have a table. The table has the columns VehicleReg | XML | ProcessedDate

My XML comes in like so:

```
<vehicles> 
  <vehicle>
    <vehiclereg>AB12CBE</vehiclereg>
    <anotherprop>BLAH</anotherprop>
  </vehicle>
  <vehicle>
    <vehiclereg>AB12CBE</vehiclereg>
    <anotherprop>BLAH</anotherprop>
  </vehicle>
</vehicles>
```

What I need to do is read the xml and insert the vehiclereg and the full vehicle xml string into each row (the dateprocessed is a getdate() so not a problem).

I was working on something like below but had no luck:

```
DECLARE @XmlData XML
Set @XmlData = EXAMPLE XML
SELECT T.Vehicle.value('(vehiclereg)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(10)') AS vehiclereg,
       T.Vehicle.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
       GETDATE()
FROM @XmlData.nodes('Vehicles/Vehicle') AS T(Vehicle)
```

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction?

Regards

Comment: There is no `Registration` element in your XML. Also, you want to store the whole XML in each row? Or just the corresponding vehicle element?

Comment: Thanks, have corrected my OP, but the issue is more selecting the full vehicle string including the tags, as i'm using this to generate a checksum to then use this to detect updates as they are imported into the database

Comment: And you have multiple `vehicle` elements with the same `vehiclereg` element value, as in your example XML? `AB12CBE` appears twice.

Comment: It's just example data, the registrations would be different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full query as you want:

```
DECLARE @XmlData XML
Set @XmlData = '<vehicles> 
  <vehicle>
    <vehiclereg>AB12CBE</vehiclereg>
    <anotherprop>BLAH</anotherprop>
  </vehicle>
  <vehicle>
    <vehiclereg>AB12CBE</vehiclereg>
    <anotherprop>BLAH</anotherprop>
  </vehicle>
</vehicles>'
SELECT T.Vehicle.value('./vehiclereg[1]', 'NVARCHAR(10)') AS vehiclereg,
       T.Vehicle.query('.'),
       GETDATE()
FROM @XmlData.nodes('/vehicles/vehicle') AS T(Vehicle)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I was using the value rather than query, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just need to remember XML is case sensitive. You had:

```
FROM @XmlData.nodes('Vehicles/Vehicle') AS T(Vehicle)
```

but you should have had:

```
FROM @XmlData.nodes('/vehicles/vehicle') AS T(Vehicle)
```

Also as TT pointed out there was no column named `Registration`

This should do it:

```
DECLARE @XmlData XML
Set @XmlData = '<vehicles> 
  <vehicle>
    <vehiclereg>AB12CBE</vehiclereg>
    <anotherprop>BLAH</anotherprop>
  </vehicle>
  <vehicle>
    <vehiclereg>AB12CBE</vehiclereg>
    <anotherprop>BLAH</anotherprop>
  </vehicle>
</vehicles>'
SELECT  Vehicle.value('(vehiclereg)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(10)') AS vehiclereg,
        Vehicle.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
       GETDATE()
FROM @XmlData.nodes('/vehicles/vehicle') AS T(Vehicle)
```

Result:

[image]

This would return XML:

```
DECLARE @XmlData XML
Set @XmlData = '<vehicles> 
  <vehicle>
    <vehiclereg>AB12CBE</vehiclereg>
    <anotherprop>BLAH</anotherprop>
  </vehicle>
  <vehicle>
    <vehiclereg>AB12CBE</vehiclereg>
    <anotherprop>BLAH</anotherprop>
  </vehicle>
</vehicles>'
SELECT T.Vehicle.value('(vehiclereg)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(10)') AS vehiclereg,
       T.Vehicle.query('.'),
       GETDATE()
FROM @XmlData.nodes('vehicles/vehicle') AS T(Vehicle)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can get the XML by [`XML.query()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191474.aspx), in this case `query('.')` on the `vehicles/vehicle` node to get the inner XML.

```sql
DECLARE @x XML=
'<vehicles> 
  <vehicle>
    <vehiclereg>AB12CBE</vehiclereg>
    <anotherprop>BLAH</anotherprop>
  </vehicle>
  <vehicle>
    <vehiclereg>AB13QQT</vehiclereg>
    <anotherprop>BLAH</anotherprop>
  </vehicle>
</vehicles>';

DECLARE @t TABLE(VehicleReg VARCHAR(128),[XML] XML,ProcessedDate DATETIME);

INSERT INTO @t(VehicleReg,[XML],ProcessedDate)
SELECT VehicleReg=n.v.value('(vehiclereg)[1]','VARCHAR(128)'),
       [XML]=n.v.query('.'),
       ProcessedDate=GETDATE()
FROM @x.nodes('vehicles/vehicle') AS n(v);

SELECT * FROM @t;
```

Result:

```
+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
| VehicleReg |                                XML                                                 |      ProcessedDate      |
+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
| AB12CBE    | <vehicle><vehiclereg>AB12CBE</vehiclereg><anotherprop>BLAH</anotherprop></vehicle> | 2016-03-01 15:21:37.640 |
| AB13QQT    | <vehicle><vehiclereg>AB13QQT</vehiclereg><anotherprop>BLAH</anotherprop></vehicle> | 2016-03-01 15:21:37.640 |
+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
```